# Why are motherboards designed for servers generally larger than regular motherboards?

Tags: motherboard

Why are motherboards designed for servers generally larger than regular motherboards? Usually servers come in larger form factors, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find server boards with 2-4 CPU slots, 16 ram slots, etc. This takes extra space. I also am guessing it has something to do with many servers being in rack mount chassis instead of desktop boxes.

Comment: Also to add RAID Risers, SCSI cards and other and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Servers require air flow adequate to how much heat they could generate. Racks do a lot to help the air flow, and if you take a look inside a server with that in mind, it'll make more sense.

Additionally, of course, what Skaughty said is correct: you can put more hardware in there, so .. You need more room.